# How to add additional header below main header on Mobile?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, header

So say my mobile site looks like this: [image]

But I want to add a secondary area below the header like this: [image]

How would you achieve this? Seems so simple, but the theme for this site has literally no customization options, so I know I gotta code it in somehow, but where do I go?

And how do I code it so that it only shows up on mobile, nothing else?

Any suggestions or help will seriously be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Tried editing the header.php file but not sure I added the right code...

Answer (score 1):

use wp_is_mobile() to check if is mobile or not

```
if(wp_is_mobile()){
// do some thing 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, where do I add this code? And then where do I add the html code for the design I want to add? In the header.php or the wordpress css customizer?

Comment: in your active theme check the header.php file 
<?php 
if(wp_is_mobile()){?>
 
Html code here 
<?php}
?>